# Como obter o conteúdo de uma tag atavés de uma consulta Linq?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Possuo o XML com a seguinte estrutura:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pessoas>
    <pessoa>
        <nome>Joao</nome>
        <email>joao.joao@outlook.com</email>
    </pessoa>   
</pessoas>
```

E estou tentando obter o conteúdo da tag <kbd>nome</kbd> com a seguinte *query* de tipo LINQ:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XElement root = XElement.Load("Pessoa.xml");            

    List<string> nomes = root.Elements("pessoas").Elements("pessoa").Select(x => (string)x.Element("nome")).ToList();

    foreach (var n in nomes) Console.WriteLine(n);

    Console.WriteLine(nomes.Count);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Devia exibir como a saída o nome `Joao` porém nada é exibido no console e a quantidade de ítens retornado pela pesquisa é 0.

Eu gostaria de saber como eu poderia obter o conteúdo da tag <kbd>nome</kbd> através de uma consulta em LINQ?

Comment: Eu não tenho como testar, veja se trocando o elemento de lugar resolve o problema: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eXzoU1

Comment: Na verdade EU não tenho como testar aqui e o que existe online, não tem a *assembly* necessário. Já vi que esqueci o `using System.Linq`, mas o problema não é este.

Comment: Chegou a alguma conclusão?

Comment: Ainda não testei o código da resposta, porém já solucionei o problema, mas se quiser responder seria ótimo :)

Comment: É que nem sei se a minha solução funciona. Eu acho que a a resposta dada está errada, mas não tenho certeza. Você pode responder também.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está tentando acessar o elemento `Root` novamente.

A seguinte alteração já resolve o seu problema:

```
root.Elements("pessoa").Select(x => (string)x.Element("nome")).ToList();
```

No seu código fica assim:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XElement root = XElement.Load("Pessoa.xml");            

    List<string> nomes = root.Elements("pessoa").Select(x => (string)x.Element("nome")).ToList();

    foreach (var n in nomes) Console.WriteLine(n);

    Console.WriteLine(nomes.Count);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```